# Opencv row method has a strange behavior

Tags: c++, opencv, mat

I'm working with OpenCv Mat access and copy in (C++). Considering the following example:

```cpp
 cv::Mat values  = cv::Mat::zeros(100, 1, CV_32FC1);
 for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
       values.at<float>(i, 1) = 10 + i;

 }

 cout<<values.at<float>(0, 1)<<endl; // prints 10
 cout<<values.at<float>(1, 1)<<endl; // prints 11
 cout<<values.row(0) <<endl; // prints 0
 cout<<values.row(1)<<endl; // prints 10
 cout<<values.row(2)<<endl; // prints 11
```

The problem is that `row(0)` always returns 0 and accessing the Mat with `row(1)...row(n)` has an offset of +1 with respect to the method `at<>()` which looks strange to me. Am I missing something or is a known issue of OpenCv?

Comment: `values.at<float>(i, 1)` is already out of bounds for a 1-col Mat. only (i,0) is valid here. please run a debug build, so you get proper exceptions thrown here (being 'one-off', - you did not initialize the 1st element)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [`Mat::zeros()`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.9/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-zeros), the way you call it is `rows = 100` `cols = 1`. When you call `values.at<float>(i, 1)` with `i = 0` you are accessing the element at row 0 and col 1, which of course is out of bounds of your Mat.

Change `values.at<float>(i, 1)` to `values.at<float>(i, 0)` and for future reference run your builds in Debug mode where OpenCV assertions will catch your errors like this one.

Comment: Thanks I completely missed that I was accessing the Mat out of bounds!